# Vi/Vim behaves quite different on remote server compared to on my local (ubuntu) PC

Tags: vim

On my local PC I am running Ubuntu 20.10 with Vim:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 11 2020 17:00:59)
Included patches: 1-716
```

In this version I can undo text with `Ctrl + u` open a file explorer with `:Explore` which is fine.

On another (remote) linux/ubuntu machine (where I don't have permission to install anything):

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-1111-azure (buildd@lcy01-amd64-016) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #123~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 01:52:07 UTC 2021
```

and:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2014.02
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2014.02
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2014.02"
```

I cannot use those Vim commands. E.g. if I:

```
:Explore
'Explore' is not implemented
```

and `Ctrl + u` does not work either. Further:

```
:help compatible
'help' is not implemented
```

I can get the version:

```
:version
1.22.1 2014-09-13 22:15:30 PDT
```

Its definitely another version of Vim(vi?) compared to the one on my host system.

Is it some vanilla/old/minimal version of **Vi** that's on this machine?

How do I know if its **Vi** or **Vim** (pretty limited info from `:version`)?

I can use the arrow keys to navigate so I expect its some minimal version of **Vim**.

Also on the remote machine:

```
$ which vi
/bin/vi
$ which vim
$ whereis vim
sh: whereis: not found
```

Comment: It doesn't look like another version of Vi(m) because even `help` is not implemented. 
What's the output of `which vim` or `whereis vim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have on that host is neither Vim nor the original vi. It is "BusyBox vi", [a partial reimplementation of vi](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c) that is part of the [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html) project.

If you want Vim, you will have to install it yourself in your `$HOME` or ask the administrator of that machine to do it for you.

---

As a side note, the ubiquity of Vim (and vi) is a sadly common misconception.

POSIX-certified systems must have a `vi` command that follows the specs but how that command is actually implemented is left to the vendor. On some systems it might be the original vi, on other systems it might be a minimal Vim, or a maximal Vim, or nvi, etc. Then you have Linux vendors, who generally try to follow the spec but are not bound to it. Then you have VM/container-oriented distributions that tend to strive for minimalism and may not even have a `vi` command to begin with. And then you have Vim itself, which can be built with or without this or that feature and has never stopped evolving anyway so two Vims are rarely the same.

Outside of the world of containers, it is relatively safe to assume the presence of a `vi` command on a Unix-like system, but where the behaviour of that command lies on a spectrum from the vi spec to a complete GUI build of the latest Vim is pretty much a game of roulette.

In the world of containers, it is best to not assume anything.

Comment: I assume you conclude that from the OS/dist and not from the info from :version ?
And in this BusyBox variant of vi how do you "undo"? For some reason it does not seem to work as in plain vi or vim.

Comment: Previous experience and a reasonably extensive domain knowledge. As for "undo", it is [supposed](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c#n138) to have `u`, just like vi. Also note that `<C-u>` is not "undo", either in vi or in Vim.

Comment: Hm Ctrl + u works fine on the version of vim I am running - see version in original post - without any changes/customization. Your are right u does work if just undos everything.

Comment: `<C-u>` isn't "undo" at all: `:help ctrl-u` (scroll upward), `:help i_ctrl-u` (delete characters before the cursor in insert mode), `:help c_ctrl-u` (same but in command-line mode). Not sure what you mean by "if just undos everything". Either way, what you have is neither the original vi, neither Vim so you'd better stop looking for what is different and what is common.